# How can I pass PHP variable through curl 'CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ' dynamically

Tags: php, api, curl

I want to dynamically sent the phone number (toNumber variable) CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to field, How can I pass this $toNumber in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to:"" field? Advanced thanks .....

```
$mobileNumber = "002233245"; //its example phone number
$prefixCode = "880";
$toNumber = $prefixCode.$mobileNumber;


//now sent message
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sms.to/v1/sms/send",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{"body": "Dear customer, Your application success.","to": "Here_I_want_to_use_dynamically_phoneNumber_variable this $toNumber here","sender_id": "Bank","callback_url": "mydomain.com"}',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "Authorization: Bearer code",
      "Accept: application/json",
      "Content-Type: application/json"
 ),
));
```

Comment: Don't role your own JSON, build an array with the data you want and then `json_encode()` the result.

Comment: Thinks it works fine.....

Answer (score 3):

Build the post data in a normal array with the appropriate data...

```
$postData = [ "body" => "Dear customer, Your application success.",
    "to" => $toNumber,
    "sender_id" => "Bank",
    "callback_url" => "mydomain.com"
];
```

pass a `json_encode`d string to the post fields (update this line)...

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData),
```

Comment: Thanks for comment... I have solved .... Your code is absolutely right..... works fine